# Passing a Collection<user defined class> as a parameter to the constructor of the class in java

Tags: java, class, collections, constructor, private

In below code snippet, how can I access variables from class B using `coll`?
I want to add data in `coll` in `A.main()` method and print all data using a loop.

```
class A{ 
   class B{ 
     String str; 
     int i1; 
     int i2;
   } 
   private Collection<B> coll; 

   public A(Collection<B> _coll){ 
     coll = _coll;
   } 
}
```

Comment: Where does your main() method belongs?

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: One immediate problem I see with your design is that the constructor requires `Collection<B>` as input, but your inner class `B` is package private.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The key point being that the constructor is public.

Comment: The title has nothing to do with "add data in coll in main() method". Is that really your question? Is your main method even in the same package?

Comment: Maybe you want to declare `B` as `public static class B`. There is no problem in doing what you want. Except that I don't understand precisely what it is, so cannot really guide you any further.

Comment: From outside `A` refer to `B` as `myAInstance.B`. Or if `B` is static, just `A.B`.

Comment: You may want to declare a constructor in `B`. Not necesary, but could be convenient. Maybe you understood this all the time.

Comment: It's a general question as I don't know how to handle above scenario. I was expecting a sample implementation.  Thanks @Ole V.V. for providing a very nice example which is very close to what I was searching for.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, that's where I fumbled and really know how to handle this case. Can you provide a modification if required in above code and provide an example showing how the program will work. It would be great if you also provide the main() function.

Comment: @shmosel The problem is in above design the constructor requires Collection<B> as input. I am dealing with this kind of situation for the first time so expecting somebody to show me a way to handle such case and how should be the main() implemented.

Comment: @PatrickParker It doesn't matter where the main() exist. I just need a working sample example of above scenario.

Comment: @KunjanShah You can put main() whichever way you like. I just need to learn how to handle a case when Collection is directly passed to Constructor of other class.

Comment: I don't see any variables in your code snippet at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do in your `main()`, is it something like this?

```
    Collection<A.B> newColl = Arrays.asList(new A.B("Lion", 114, 1), new A.B("Java", 9, -1));
    A myAInstance = new A(newColl);
    myAInstance.printAll();
```

If I am guessing correctly, the code below can do it. If not, please edit your question and explain.

```
public class A {
    public static class B {
        String str;
        int i1;
        int i2;

        public B(String str, int i1, int i2) {
            this.str = str;
            this.i1 = i1;
            this.i2 = i2;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%-10s%4d%4d", str, i1, i2);
        }
    }

    private Collection<B> coll;

    // in most cases avoid underscore in names, especailly names in the public interface of a class
    public A(Collection<B> coll) {
        this.coll = coll;
        // or may make a "defensive copy" so that later changes to the collection passed in doesn’t affect this instance
        // this.coll = new ArrayList<>(coll);
    }

    public void printAll() {
        // Requirements said "print all data using a loop", so do that
        for (B bInstance : coll) {
            System.out.println(bInstance);
            // may also access variables from B, for instance like:
            // System.out.println(bInstance.str + ' ' + bInstance.i1 + ' ' + bInstance.i2);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the code I suggested for `main()` will print:

```
Lion       114   1
Java         9  -1
```

Comment: Yes, This is what I was expecting.